# Initialization with two constants like "init (items newItems: [FeedItem],sourceURL newURL: NSURL)"

Tags: swift

```
class Feed {

    let items: [FeedItem]
    let sourceURL: NSURL

    init (items newItems: [FeedItem],sourceURL newURL: NSURL) {
        self.items = newItems
        self.sourceURL = newURL
    }
```

I'm confused about this, why there are two constants in init?(for example,`items` and `newItems`),what can they do? and when I need them?

(I'm not sure whether I described this question properly, any suggestions are welcome )

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. There are 2 class variables to initialize, so the init function will take 2 parameters to initialize them. In the initializer the class variables are set to the respective variables that were passed to it. Nothing out of the ordinary for an initializer.

Comment: @yesthisisjoe Thanks, I 'm not familiar with this expression.Now I got it.